# NodeJs Method Chaining of fs.mkdir and fs.rename

Tags: node.js, express

I'm working on a file uploader script which creates a new folder (based on the timestamp) and moves the uploaded file to the created folder.

`Sometimes it works` and sometimes I'm getting a ENOENT rename Error (file/folder not exist).

The following code is in my post route:

```
var form = new multiparty.Form({
   uploadDir: "C:"+ path.sep + "files"
});

form.parse(req, function(err, fields, files) {

   var dirPath = "C:"+ path.sep + "files" + path.sep + +new Date;

   fs.mkdir(dirPath, 0777, function(err, dirPath){

      if (err) console.error(err);

      console.log("Created new folder");

      fs.rename(files.file[i].path, dirPath + path.sep + files.file[i].originalFilename, function(err){

         if (err) console.error(err);

         console.log("Moved file");

      });

   }(err, dirPath));

   next();
});
```

I'm using [express(4)](http://expressjs.com/) and the [multiparty module](https://github.com/andrewrk/node-multiparty/).
As you can see I'm using `async` functions.

So the question is: What is wrong with my code?

**Edit**

The error I'm talking about: `"Error: ENOENT, rename 'C:\files\7384-1r41cry.png'"`

It has something to do with a race condition. With `fs.mkdirSync` everything works fine.

Comment: @SomeKittens Ux2666 yes this is express

Answer (score 0):

Ok a few things...

1. you really should start using promises, it makes the code easier to read and the error handling is way superior. I usually use when.js, but there are other alternatives.
2. you should throw the errors or return on errors or you would try to continue running the function even when the previous operations failed.

you do

```
if (err) console.error(err);
```

should be

```
if (err) throw err;
```

Comment: inreally would like to know why i was down voted. please correct me if i was wring in my assertions

Comment: Why are people downvoting the answers here? Stop it or I will call the staff. Thank you for your answer Dayan  +1

Comment: I'm going to check out promises and stuff to avoid race condition +1

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be some sort of race condition happening here.
This kind of stuff is easy to get wrong and hard to get it right.

I normally use `gulp` for this kind of stuff and maybe should you :)

To copy a whole directory tree into some other directory wouldn't be easier.

```
gulp.src('./inputDir/**/*').pipe(gulp.dest('./outputDir')
```

And all files from `inputDir` would be **copied** into `outputDir`

But maybe coping is not a option. The files could too large, right?
Lets hack it a bit to make it work the way we want.

```
var fs = require('fs')
, gulp = require('gulp')
, thr = require('through2').obj
, SRC = './test/**/*.{css,html,js}' // it could be 'my/file/located/here'
, OUT = './output' // it could be 'my/newer/file/located/there'
;


gulp.src(SRC)
.pipe(thr(function(chunk, enc, next){
  chunk.contents = new Buffer('') // cleaning the contents of the file
  chunk._originalPath = chunk.path
  next(null, chunk)
}))
.pipe(gulp.dest(OUT))
.pipe(thr(function(chunk, enc, next){
  // now a place holder file exists at our destination.
  // so we can write to it and being convident it exists
  console.log('moving file from', chunk._originalPath, 'to', chunk.path)
  fs.rename(chunk._originalPath, chunk.path, function(err){
    if (err) return next(err)
    next()
  })
}))
```

This moves all css, html and js files from `input` to `output`, regardless of how many nested directories there are

gulp is awesome :)

Comment: Why are people downvoting the answers here? Stop it or I will call the staff. Thank you for your answer Markuz - I'm sure its a sort of race condition in my script. Thank you for the hint +1